# Gallery captures trackball navigation

Tags: android

The Gallery traps trackball/dpad navigation horizontally.

Here's an example layout with buttons on either side of a Gallery:

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Gallery
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/gallery"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
 </LinearLayout>
```

When you navigate into the gallery with the trackball you can't escape to the buttons on either side.  I tried adding android:nextFocusLeft="@id/button" to the gallery.  I also tried adding it to the first view in the gallery's adapter.

Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this out, it is a bug in Gallery.  The workaround it is to extend Gallery as follows:

```
public class DpadableGallery extends Gallery {

    public DpadableGallery(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }
    public DpadableGallery(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        switch (keyCode) {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_LEFT:
             if (getSelectedItemPosition()==0) {
                 return false;
             }
            break;
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_RIGHT:
            if (getSelectedItemPosition()==(getAdapter().getCount()-1)) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

}
```